# I edited an answer, but it shows as edited by another user

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits

I suggested an edit for this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4305487/262852

I mean, it's the most minor edit. The edit was approved, but it doesn't show as edited by me. Why?

Is it because my edits need approval?

Comment: Because another user [edited after you](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/4305487/revisions)...

Comment: ok dokey, no prob.

Comment: And [ecoologic](http://stackoverflow.com/users/465915/ecoologic) is not a moderator. Moderators, like [animuson♦](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/246246/animuson) above, have a diamond next to their name

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another user selected the "improve edit" option when reviewing your suggested edit.

They then changed both instances of `ctx` to `context`.

Your edit was approved by the community user on submission of the above but then instantly replaced by the "improved" edit so it is only visible in the edit history.

You still get the +2 for an approved suggested edit in this scenario.

Comment: it just seems weird, that's all.  the plus 2 is neither here nor there.  curious.