# Should a high-rep user post the edit as his own even if it adds nothing new to already suggested proposal?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

First off, this is not the classic case of "My name is not showing as editor" as cited [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311166/is-it-normal-for-2k-users-to-hijack-edits-coming-in-after-a-major-edit-maki) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274296/i-edited-an-answer-but-it-shows-as-edited-by-another-user). Two of my recent edits were recently taken over by users with 2k+ reputation. First one was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10395256). When I proposed the edit, the user had everything jumbled up in code block. I rectified it. Later I saw that it had been rejected because post was edited by another user (2k+ rep) who had actually made a grave mistake while editing it. I was surprised that how could two simultaneous edits be pending for approval when I clearly get the message "an edit is already pending for this post" if I try to edit some posts. Then I thought maybe he got it from review stack. So anyways I corrected his mistake, submit it for approval and notify him via comment. He acknowledged his mistake like a gentleman and corrected his mistake himself. So that's another rejected edit for me. I thought okay fine, things happen.

Then there was this [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10395449). I submitted an edition and it was already approved by two people when It was also rejected for the same reason. I went back and saw a high reputation holding user had edited the post without a single change in my proposed edit. I asked him what was going on there and he said, "*I picked this Edit from review->Suggested Edit*". I don't know but this does not sound good to be honest. I am not sure what goes on in suggested edit review stack but even if approvers feel the need to contribute to that suggestion, does not the original proposal still get approved?  I am annoyed because it has damaged my edit record by adding three rejected edits as compared to my approved edits. Can you folks help me understand what went on there? Under what circumstances can high rep users take over already suggested proposals? What is the exact behaviour there?
**EDIT:** This [Meta Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299397/are-2k-rep-users-overwritting-suggested-edits?rq=1) is also helpful on this topic. 
**NOTE:** Just to make things clear, I am not blaming either one of those two guys. They are also doing this because of a passion for this platform.

Comment: Just noticed this wasn't your post that you were asking about, the important thing is that the post is edited to become clearer, not the person that edited it. I honestly wouldn't worry about it and just edit as you see is necessary, when you get enough reputation your edits won't need a review

Comment: Why do you need to complain in the comments every time a 2K user's edit trumps yours.  If you see the edit and missed something, go back and do it again without the commentary.  The comments are just noise and are unnecessary.

Comment: @psubsee2003 An earlier meta post of mine was of course whining. This however is about knowing the exact behavior. Do you have anything to add on that? If yes, please contribute. If no, there are better ways to respond than assumptions. The posts mentioned are speaking for themselves.

Comment: @NSNoob I'm not talking about this meta post.  You have a question about how the system works and are asking it on meta.  That's what meta is for.  I'm talking about the comments on the individual posts.  That is not want comments are for.

Comment: Earn 1100 more rep, and this will not be a problem anymore.

Comment: @Sayse that is a helpful comment. But as you can see, in the second post, it is basically the same edit as the suggested proposals. That is surely not okay is it?

Comment: @psubsee2003 erm so you mean that I should not have notified the editor about his mistake and simply edited it to rectify his mistake for the first post? And for the second post, the comment was to gather necessary data for this meta post.

Comment: I don't really dwell on it, just move on to the next edit, that particular edit could have been done by selecting all the text and pressing ctrl+k so it didn't take much effort

Comment: @Sayse Yes that is true. I just think this would reflect badly on my record for future edits when approvers see hey this guy has X approved suggestions and Y rejected suggestions, not probably the best suggestion after all.

Comment: @Yannis I am aiming for that. Wasted a whole year and now making up for that lost time in this quarter. :)

Comment: I never look at the editors track record, I'm only ever concerned with whether or not the *edit* should be approved

Comment: The second example was from Help and Improvement, so it was probably a coincidence that they formatted the question the same way you did.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All of this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).  The edit system is designed such that an edit from a 2K user will always override any suggested edits in the queue.

In most cases, when this happens, it is likely due to simultaneous editing and not any kind of conscious effort to reject your edit and replace it with theirs.  What usually happens is:

1. You click edit and start editing the post.
2. A 2K user sees the same post and starts editing
3. You commit your edit (the review process begins now).  At this point, the edit link on the post is actually replaced by a link to the suggested edit for 2K users (or disabled for <2K users), so no one else can try to edit it directly.  If a 2K user tries, they are taken to the review.
4. The 2K user finishes his/her edit.  Your edit is rejected without prejudice.

In virtually all cases, they probably never even knew your edit existed because they can't see any record of it.

Now, while the edit link itself is actually replaced with a link to the review, it is possible to hack the URL to get to the edit page as a 2K user, but I don't see this happening very often.  Given the speed with which the review queue moves, it is extremely difficult to see a pending edit, go the the original post, hack the URL, make all of the edits and finish before the suggested edit is approved.

I'd just pass this off as bad luck.  The rejected edits do not really impact you (unless you have a very long series of rejected edits), so it's not really something to worry about.  Go find another post to edit, there are plenty of them.

Comment: Yes I did find [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299397/are-2k-rep-users-overwritting-suggested-edits?rq=1) talking about URL hacking but tbh it seems to much trouble for its worth, as you stated. Specially when there is no rep for them in it anyways. Luckily my ratio of accepted and rejected edits is not bad. I have had troubles with simultaneous editing before as well. Except that in this case rejection came too long after the suggestion which sort of puts the simultaneous editing out of the equation

Comment: But in any case, this does explain what might have been going on there. So I suppose I am gonna mark it as the answer.

Comment: Is there an exact reason as to _why_? Sometimes it feels like 30% of my suggested edits are rejected because a 2K user edits it after I submit my edit. While the missing +2 doesn't _really_ bother me (it _is_ a tad annoying), it could be seen as a bit unfair to users who are just beginning on SO.